# Facebook api video.upload requires HTTPS connection

Tags: facebook, video, file-upload

I noticed a very funny error message Facebook API returns when I tried to use CURL to upload video to Facebook as below:

---

### This method requires an HTTPS connection

Based on facebook api doc: developers.facebook.com/docs/ref … deo.upload
it wrote that:

Video uploads to Facebook happen on a specific set of servers. When you call video.upload, you need to account for this fact. You must make the video.upload call to http://api-video.facebook.com, and not api.facebook.com. If you call api.facebook.com, an error gets returned.

Curiously, I tried to change the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS then I got a different error message. This time. it is telling me that the host does not exist.

Could anyone please help?

Here is my php code

Code:

$args = array(
                      'method' => 'video.upload',
                      'title'       => 'my video',
                      'description' => 'Test my video upload via API',
                      'access_token'=> $facebook->getAccessToken(),
                      'api_key'=>$fbconfig['api']
                );
                $args["kdVBRO1IU.flv"] = '@'.SITE_PATH.'temp/kdVBRO1IU.flv';

```
            //echo $args["AtXAI8Pdt.flv"];
            //$statusUpdate = $facebook->api($args);

             $ch = curl_init();  
             $url = 'http://api-video.facebook.com/restserver.php';  
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);  
             $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input BeRecursive, It took me awhile to get it working
The URl I used is

http://api-video.facebook.com/facebook.upload.video

Quite strange as I could not find a single document mention about this URL, however, following one of the post on facebook developer forum then I got it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the forum post?  the url you posted here doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I can't see to get this to work either.  Here is a post that i see also that has not been answered by facebook.  Wonder if this is a bug. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=267984  found a bug reference also i think http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12696

Comment: Perhaps facebook has changed the URL again. At the time I got it working I had to use the old URL, now perhaps need to use the new one.